# I'm travelling to the UK to study and I must continue a vaccine treatment, how do I do it?

Tags: united-kingdom, study, health

I get a vaccine shot every month, and I get to store the doses in my fridge. However now at the end of September I am travelling to the UK to study there. I am from Spain and I was told by my doctor that people have previously done it and translated all the required documents to English.

However I don't know who I should contact there and how to arrange it. I also don't know how I would take the vaccines with me because they must be in the fridge at all times. They can be out of the fridge for like an hour / hour and a half. No more. And the trip from here to when I reach my destination and get to a fridge will be a lot of hours. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few products are designed to keep medication (such as insulin) cool while travelling, some for as long as 48 hours, and might work for you. A quick search on Amazon turned up any number of choices such as  [ThermaFreeze](https://www.amazon.es/Paquete-hielo-reutilizable-Thermafreeze-grandes/dp/B003ET2G74/ref=sr_1_24?ie=UTF8&qid=1472482190&sr=8-24&keywords=Techni-ICE) and [Frio](https://www.amazon.es/Frio-Bolsa-isot%C3%A9rmica-mantener-insulina/dp/B001LNUSCK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1472482521&sr=8-1&keywords=frio). The [Frio website](http://www.friouk.com/shop.aspx) has lots of other options, helpful FAQs, and links about travelling with medications, and a vendor in Madrid.

Check ahead with your airline, advising them what you are carrying, as well as looking at the regulations in Spain. Have them in your carry-on luggage, not in checked baggage. Generally, you advise security that you are carrying essential medication, have a letter from your physician (original, not a copy), and the prescription. Both should be accompanied by English translations for entry into the UK.  And a suggestion: review the [UK regulations regarding what may not be brought into the country](https://www.gov.uk/travelling-controlled-drugs).

And, similarly, on your departure from England, [gov.uk guidance](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/essential-medicines-and-medical-equipment):

> You can take medical equipment with you if it's essential for your journey. The equipment is screened separately and you must show documentation from a qualified medical professional, such as a letter from your doctor.